# How to find the Config File location via ConfigurationManager?

Tags: asp.net, .net, configurationmanager

How to find the Config File location via ConfigurationManager?

I have the ConfigurationManager class in code and I'm debugging it. I'd like to know to which config file it's pointing to (web.config or app.config, etc).

Is there any property or method on the ConfigurationManager that can help with this?

Answer (score 11):

The configuration file itself is represented by [Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object. To get this object, run this:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Then you can view the file path via `config.FilePath`.

**Update.** As pointed out by [Schadensbegrenzer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3528503/schadensbegrenzer) for web application you will need another code to load the config file:

```
Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
```

Comment: Your solution would not work for web application. In web applications you have to use System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~")